# Extracting Oracle geometry with FME's SQL Executor transformer

Tags: sql, geometry, fme-form

I am wondering why my SQL executor can't extract the geometry from my Oracle database. The geometry are polygons.

I added the 'SHAPE' column to the query in the executor, and I exposed the attribute but there is still 'no geometry available'.

Most of the time, this problem doesn't happen when using 'SQL Creator' (which in my case here is querying another dB).

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is your sql script. There maybe a geometry error that is causing the retrieval to fail (like a point that is 2002 sdo_geom but should be line)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a Combine Geometry parameter in the transformer. Have you got that set to Result Geometry Only?

[image]

If this is set then I believe the geometry comes out with the query, without having to specify the column name, like here:

[image]

A couple of other thoughts - maybe too obvious - but you are using the Oracle Spatial Object reader (not Oracle Non-Spatial)? And are you getting any results at all? Like is it returning attributes from Oracle but no geometry? It could be that there are no results being matched. Perhaps there are parameters for the Oracle format that need setting?

Also, are there any warnings in the log file? That could spell out what the problem is. As a last resort, run it again with Tools > FME Options > Translation > Log Debug set. That might return some extra messages to help with debugging (just don't leave it on all the time because it will return messages that could be misconstrued outside of debugging).